# Excel VBA Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

Good evening. As the title implies: I require help with an Excel macro, that determines if there's anything in 2 cells, then in a third one the result of their subtract.
I tried fiddling with the data and cell type. No results.
Using: [h]:mm;@  and the data in the cells are "Time" in 24H Format.

```
 Dim e As Integer
 Dim r As Integer
 Dim w As Integer
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim q As Integer
 Dim one As String
 Dim two As String
 Dim k as long 

 q = 3
 w = 5
 e = 3
 r = 3
 i = 4

   For k = 1 To 7
       one = Cells(e, r).Value
       two = Cells(e, i).Value
       If Cells(e, r).Value > 0 And Cells(e, i).Value > 0 Then
           Cells(q, w) = Cells(e, i).Value - Cells(e, r).Value
           'pas.Cells(q, w) = two - one
           'Range(q, w) = Cells(e, i).Value - Cells(e, r).Value
       else
           cells(q,w) = 0
       end if
   next k
```

Comment: 1) What line is throwing the error? 2) Please provide a [mcve] -- there are a mass of undeclared variables in your code, including ones whose initialization lies in code that you have not shown. Your code lacks the context required to answer your question (in any way other than a lucky guess)

Comment: declare `one` and `two` as double.

Comment: And make sure the data does not have any strings or errors as those will cause your error.

Comment: The error appears on the attempt at subtracting both. I tried declaring one and two as integer but that did not work,

Comment: And pas. is a shortcut for a worksheet.

Comment: The commented code is the attempts at other ways for the subtracting. I also attempted to change where i would "save" the subtract. No result.

Comment: The code attempts to subtract 2 hours. And place it in an empty cell

Comment: Error shows at: "Cells(q, w) = Cells(e, i).Value - Cells(e, r).Value"

Comment: Tried the "Double" suggestion. No result.

Comment: Edited the code, it is now a reproducible example.

Comment: Are you sure the data is truly a time and not a string that looks like a time?  Try changing the number format to general, do you get a decimal number?

Comment: It is a time, saved as text in a worksheet, and placed inside another worksheet as an "hour" format.   And now it is a subtract of two hours from within the same worksheet.

Comment: `saved as text`. There you have it. If you change the format of the cell to General, does it show as a number?

Comment: Well, in the 1st worksheet is "text", but it shows as an Hour.   Then, i copy it to the 2nd worksheet, with the hour format.                         When i attempt the subtract: the popup shows "error 13 mismatch".      The thing that keeps me busy...... I try the same code elsewhere.... and it Works.  I try in the main work code... And it doesn't. Do i have to clear the values? even tho i reasign values to them?

Comment: Lesson one.. always use `Option Explicit` & Compile your code!

Comment: "elsewhere" the data may be really time values. Again, what happens when you format the cells as "General"? If they don't change to decimal numbers, they are TEXT and you need to convert them to real time values if you want to do maths with them.

Comment: Oh....... I change it to general, nothing happens. Value "05:35" remains the same. It is a text. DEM.   How can i convert them to time values? Without messing with the "hour" format on the cells?  The place where i paste them is in Hour format. Does that change the text value to hour? Or does it remain in Text? Still can't do math.

Comment: Thanks for the help every1. It worked! Had to change the values to "number". And refrain from recycling variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a formula? Cells are formatted using 24hr time "HHmm" however A1 & B1 data is as per below.

A1 = `1:30:00 PM` displayed as `1330`

B1 = `2:55:00 PM` displayed as `1455`

Formula for C1 `=IF(OR(A1="",B1=""),0,B1-A1)` result displayed as `0125`